# CSS :first-letter pseudo selector - Apply changes to first character whatever it is

Tags: html, css

There are situations where the first character is different from first letter.

See this:

```
<style>.sizer:first-letter { font-size: 50px; }</style>
<span class="sizer">?HI ALL</span>
```

By using `:first-letter` pseudo selector the browser seems to take `?H`, so it's editing the size of the first 2 characters.

How to set it up CSS to take only the question mark (or anyway the first character whatever it is)?

Comment: Is the text inside the span constant, or are you looking for a solution that will work with different variations?

Comment: It looks like there's no way to have a solution with dynamic values. Check the open discussion about this topic here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2040

Comment: @ChenBr *Is the text inside the span constant, or are you looking for a solution that will work with different variations?* **The second you write. CSS that replaces the style of each first char.**

Comment: @ChenBr *It looks like there's no way to have a solution with dynamic values. Check the open discussion about this topic here: github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2040* Nothing of new. ** Who invented css did not think of such a simple thing. Shocked.**

Answer (score 2):

> By using before css selector you can append ? icon or whatever you want, hope it helps !
>
> ```css
> .sizer:first-letter {
>   font-size:40px;
> }
> .sizer:before{
>   content:'?';
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>Page Title</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <p class="sizer"><span>HI ALL</span></p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Like *@ChenBr* wrote seems that with CSS it's impossible.

So, for whoever is groping in the dark like me the only one way it's JS.

The way with JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    selector = $(".sizethis");
    for (i=0; i<selector.length; i++) {
        selector[i].innerHTML = '<span class="yourstyle">'+selector[i].innerHTML.trim().substr(0,1) + '</span>' + selector[i].innerHTML.trim().substr(1,selector[i].innerHTML.trim().length);
        //console.log(selector[i].innerHTML);
    }
});
```